# Permission denied even with 777 and disabled selinux

Tags: permissions, selinux

On a centos 6.5 machine I wanted to create a general user, where its home directory is shared among many users, called shareduser

/home/shareduser has mod 700
Then the shared folder is called: /home/shareduser/storage has the mod 777 with owner and group = shareduser
further selinux is disabled

Whenever I'm cd with my own user(moataz) into the folder I get permission denied

any ideas?
Cheers,

Comment: This is the expected behavior if /home/shareduser has mode 700. It should be 710 if you want to be able to cd to any subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

The mod 700 means only the owner of `/home/shareduser` can read/write/execute (I forget what execute means wrt. directories).  From the wiki page on [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod), it looks like you, at minimum, want the execute bit set on the group flags, but you also have to make sure that all related users are assigned to the group assigned to `/home/shareduser` (see [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)) so that they can recurse within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change SELinux. This may solve your problem to set 'Permissive' or '0'(zero). 
`$ setenforce [Permissive|0]`

To make changes persistent through a system reboot, edit the 'SELINUX=' line in `/etc/selinux/config` for either 'enforcing', 'permissive', or 'disabled'. For example: `SELINUX=permissive`